# How to get started with learning in Django

Tags: django

I am new on Django and Python. I want to write a program with Django. So please share me useful ideas and concept. How can I set up Django  in my Windows OS.

I am confused and occur some errors while I read ebooks. Share me with all experiences please in step by step.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Dude, this question you've got here is akin to "tell me everything about Django", which simply isn't a valid question to ask.  Consider asking about the installation first.  What did you try?  What errors did you get? You need to focus your question because this will likely just get closed as it is written.  You need to elaborate on what the problem is, honestly, and then folks might be able to assist you.

Comment: rtfm: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/install/

Comment: You can register for my upcoming skillshare class if still interested in learning Django: http://skl.sh/17FtUju

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you should do is get yourself a project, it can be anything.  The classic django-learning project is a blog.

Python is fairly easy to learn once you have some programming experience. I recommend that you go through the [official tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).  This [Google class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/) also looks pretty good.  You don't need to know the standard library all that much -- just enough python to find your way around whenever you need something.  I'd say you can pick up python in a few afternoons of work.

After that, go through the [Django tutorial](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/intro/tutorial01/#intro-tutorial01) to get an idea of how to get started.  Then start with your project using the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/) which are quite good.  They also contain an overview and installation section which may be handy. After you've gotten your feet wet, read the [Django book](http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/) and then go fix all the things that could be better about your project.

Just like with any kind of programming, the key is to be constantly practising and improving your code.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.djangobook.com is your friend. Free, well written and generally ace.

Comment: +1 as its written by one of Django's Benevolent Dictators for Life

Answer (score 1):

First, if you're new in python [read dive into python](http://www.diveintopython.net/), you must use python 2.5 or 2.6 not 3 (for django at least)

For windows [here's a good tutorial](http://wiki.thinkhole.org/howto:django_on_windows). Then read the [djangobook](http://www.djangobook.com)

For further information you can read [Pro Django](http://apress.com/book/view/1430210478)

And remember the [oficial docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/) is very well written.

This may help you to start

Answer (score 1):

This is great resource for you [Getting Started with Django](http://gettingstartedwithdjango.com/)

Enjoy.